# Use parent node not children - jQuery .each(function())

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery to grab results from a webservice(3rd party can't change).  A result set is something like:

```
<result> 
 <contactId>1234</contactId> 
 <contactState>9</contactState> 
 <contactStateSortOrder>5</contactStateSortOrder>
  <address>
    <addressId>568</addressId> 
    <contactId>9801</contactId> 
  </address>
</result>
```

Now I am using

```
$('result', xml).each(function() {
   $("contactId", this).text();
  });
```

to get the contact id out and doing what i need to do however the end result is 
12349801 all i would like is the 1234. Any ideas?

Thanks in advvace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your selector. To get 1234 in your example, use `result > contactId`; to get 9801 use `address > contactId`

You could also do `contactId:not(adress > contactId)`

Answer (score 0):

Either this:

```
$('result > contactId', xml).each(function() {
  $(this).text();
});
```

or this:

```
$('result', xml).each(function() {
  $(this).children("contactId").text();
});
```